# NSProgressIndicator not work in Objective C Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, progress-bar, nsprogressindicator

I try to use NSProgressINdicator to show the process progress. However when I use on Cocoa Storyboard it's not working at all, even very simple set a value to show status of NSProgress Indicator.
I check on internet and saw some NSProgressIndicator can work on NSView. However, here I want to run in Storyboard.

[ViewController.m]

```
- (IBAction)test:(id)sender {
_progressBar.maxValue = 100;
for(int i=0; i<100;i++)
{
    _progressBar.doubleValue = i;
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
}
}
```

Setting for progressBar:
[image: Setting for progressBar:]

[image: When I run it only show like this]

Comment: Is `_progressBar` nil? Did you actually connect the control to the IBOutlet in Interface Builder?

Comment: Yes, it have been executed. However, progressBar didn't update any thing. Even try simple set: progressBar.doublevalue =50; progressBar still showing empty as photo.

Comment: Your `test:` action blocks the main thread, and will not work as expected. You need to run your loop in a background thread, and then dispatch the progress bar updates.

Comment: It sounds like _progressBar is nil

Comment: @TheNextman I don't think reason by lack off background. thread. Even simple set  progressBar.doubleValue = 80; then complete method . NSprogressindicator still doesn't update anything.

Comment: @TheNextman I already binding IBOutlet to Viewcontroller.h. However as photo you can seem seem it can't not connect success full. (circle without blue dot). Do you know how to binding this case.

Comment: When I debug seem can't setDouble value to progressBar. after progressBar.doubleValue = 80, progressBar value still =0;

Comment: You need to figure out why the connection between the storyboard and header don't work. Without that, _progressBar will be nil and doing anything with it will not work.

Comment: @TheNextman progressBar already connected to storyboard, last time Mainclass if difference. However still not work now